# Install Adobe Garamond (pfb, afm) for MikTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'd like to replace the URW-Garamond in my document with Adobe Garamond.

I got the 6 pfb- and pfm-files and couldn't find a way to install it for MikTex.

Comment: Use Walter Schmidt’s support files: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/w-a-schmidt

Comment: Or compile with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`: if they're installed as system fonts, just add `\setmainfont{Adobe Gramond Pro}` and compile (however, do not load `inputenc` nor `fontenc`.

Comment: @Bernard I’ve never managed to use `pfb` files with `fontspec`; I thought that support for them was a plan for the future.  Is there a way to get them working now?

Comment: Sorry! I thought you had the .otf files…

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, by have you considered using `ebgaramond`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution.

Unlike agaramon.txt says I had to use

`\usepackage{xgaramon}` AND 
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: I didn't even think of asking whether you had loaded fontenc:)!

Answer (score 3):

(Almost) all necessary instructions are given at the above-mentioned link. What you have to do is  to download the `pad.txt` and  `pad.zip` files. Unzip the contents of pad.zip at the root of a `LocalTeXMF` tree.  If you do not have one yet, create one first wih `MiKTeX Settings` (`Roots` tab) (click on the `Add` button for this, see image below). Do *not* unzip in MiKTeX 2.9. Your Local TeXMF tree *must* be independent from MiKTeX 2.9, else its contents may be deleted on updates.

Then, in your `LocalTeXMF\fonts`directory, create a `type1` directory and copy the `pfb`s in it, renaming them as indicated in `pad.map`; do the same for the `pfm`s (actually, I think these are not really necessary, as TeX uses the  `tfm`s).

Last step: make your system aware of all the stuff. Refresh the `FNBD` (via MiKTeX Settings, `General` tab). And last — not least, make dvips know where to grab the real fonts: write in your personal `updmap.cfg` the line : `Map pad.map`, and run from the console: `updmap --verbose`. This will the fonts be mentioned in `psfonts.map` and some other files of the sort, that `dvips`, `pdflatex`, `dvipdfm`, &c. read to find type 1 fonts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mistyped the file extensions: I got the afm and pfb files. 

I created a localtexmf and added it to miktex options. I extracted the pad.zip in this directory and added the renamed afm and pfb-files, refreshed the FNDB, added pad.map to updmap and tried to include the files by `\usepackage{xagaramon}` but it doesn't work. 

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't say you ran `updmap` from  the command line. If  you didn't, they don't appear in `dvips.map` and the like, so the dvips, pdflatex, &c., can't find the `pfb`s. You can check the contents of these files: they're located in `C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config`.

Comment: Oops!  I mistyped the name of the file: it's `psfonts.map`, not dvips.map.

Comment: I ran `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` inserted `Map pad.map`, saved and ran `initexmf --mkmaps` like it's told in MikTeX manual. Furthermore I opened `updmap.cfg`, added `Map pad.map` and ran `updmap --verbose`. Nothing worked.

Comment: Did you check the contents of `psfonts.map`? You should find there `padr8r` and its friends referred to.

Comment: http://oi62.tinypic.com/23jkbgx.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14558/discussion-between-bernard-and-moldevort)